# MySQL return case value

Tags: mysql, case

I'm looking for a way to return the value that was "case"-ed on.

e.g. what will return me the md5 result **without** recomputing it at the then statement

```
SELECT 
CASE md5(col1,col2,col3,...,coln) 
WHEN MD5('') then NULL 
else ???
end
```

Comment: repeat the statement

Comment: @juergend thanks but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Is it about code duplication or performance?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel code duplication

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to repeat a calculation multiple times in the select list, then you need to push it into a subquery and reference the field alias set in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
    CASE t1.calc 
        WHEN MD5('') then NULL 
        else t1.calc
    end as md_5
FROM
    (select md5(col1,col2,col3,...,coln) as calc from table) t1
```